# проверить, если ВСЕ элементы одного списка есть в элементе второго списка, то вывести элемент второго списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Текст задания: На вход программе подается натуральное число n, затем n строк, затем число k — количество поисковых запросов, затем k строк — поисковые запросы. Напишите программу, которая выводит все введенные строки, в которых встречаются ВСЕ поисковые запросы.
Моя логика: считываю всю информацию, создаю два списка. Далее нужно пробежаться через цикл и проверить если ВСЕ элементы одного списка есть в элементе второго списка, то вывести элемент второго списка. Застрял на последнем этапе. Заранее спасибо.

````
   q = []
   k = []
   for i in range(n):
       a = input()
       q.append(a)
   m = int(input())
   for i in range(m):
       b = input()
       k.append(b)
   flag = False    
   for i in range(len(k)):
       for j in range(len(q)):
           if k[i] in q[j]:
           flag = True```
````

Answer (score 1):

Для разнообразия вот ещё через `list comprehension` и с использованием встроенной функции `all`, зря её что ли придумали:

```
texts = ['Наш паровоз вперёд летит', 'Однажды в студёную зимнюю пору', 'Однажды паровоз летит вперёд внезапно']
query = ['Однажды', 'паровоз', 'внезапно']
print([t for t in texts if all(q in t for q in query)])
```

Вывод:

```
['Однажды паровоз летит вперёд внезапно']
```

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, нужна логика примерно такая:

```
for s in strings:            # введённые строки
     flag = True 
     for q in queries:       #запросы
          if not (q in s):   #если хоть один запрос не найден
               flag = False
               break         #ловить больше нечего
     if flag:
          print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

можно так

```
def my_fun(n):
    my_list = []
    for i in range(n):
        el_lista = input()
        my_list.append(el_lista)
    return(my_list)

q = my_fun(int(input()))
k = my_fun(int(input()))

for i in range(len(k)):
    if k[i] in q:
        flag = True
    else:
        flag = False
        break

if flag:
    print(k)
```